# How to increase the efficiency for sorting an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Below is the code to sort the numeric values in increasing order, it works fine for lower values of `L`, but is not efficient when value of `L` goes *up-to / beyond* **1,000,000**.

```
for(i=0; i<L; i++) {
    for(j=i+1; j<L; j++) {
        if(SARAY[j] < SARAY[i]) { 
                temp = SARAY[i];
            SARAY[i] = SARAY[j];
            SARAY[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me improvement over it ?

Comment: you can try `quicksort`. Its quite fast.

Comment: can you give me a specific example? thanks so much

Comment: Removed the MATLAB tag. Your question isn't related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example on how to use `qsort` which will be much faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const int *ia = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types
  const int *ib = (const int *)b;
  return (*ia > *ib) - (*ia < *ib);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int j;

  int numbers[] = { 7, 3, 4, 1, -1, 23, 12, 43, 2, -4, 5 };
  size_t numbers_len = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int);

  qsort(numbers, numbers_len, sizeof(int), int_cmp);

  for(j = 0; j < numbers_len; j++) printf("%d\n", numbers[j]);
}
```

This will print the integers in ascending order (starting with the lowest number).

If you want to print the integers in descending order (starting with the highest number) you can just inverse the loop

```
for(j = numbers_len-1; j >= 0; j--) printf("%d\n", numbers[j]);
```

Comment: `return *ia  - *ib;` can cause **undefined behaviour** since `int` does not wrap. Better is to test for `>` then `<` otherwise they are the same.

Comment: my array will go up to 1000000 dimension, do you think it will work?

Comment: @YuchenYang If it causes problems you can always change to `long long int` and then change the pointer type for `ia` and `ib` to the corresponding type.

Comment: @Linus that is nifty +1.

Comment: sorry, forgot to say, it's not integer elements ,but float between 0 and 1

Comment: @YuchenYang since the updated answer does not test for equality (big danger with real numbers) it should work, with the appropriate type casts.

Answer (score 0):

There are many algorithms exist which are good enough to fulfill your requirement. Each of them has their own pros and cons.

Here, i am going to talk about two algorithms

1. Quick Sort.
2. Merge Sort.

### Quick Sort

Its time-complexities are:

- Average-Case Time Complexity - **O(n.log(n))**
- Worst-Case Time Complexity   - **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

**Pros:**
It takes at least **O(log(n))** and at most **O(n) extra** space on the stack to sort the array, as pointed out by [rcgldr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282056/rcgldr).

**Cons:**
Since, its worst case time complexity is of order - **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. Therefore, it is **not** always an improvement over your algorithm. Therefore, i am directly jumping into another algorithm.

---

### Merge Sort

As the name suggests, here the sorting is carried out by **Divide - Conquer** Method. Where, first the large array is broken into smaller array and then smaller array are merged together in sorted order and this process is done recursively.

> For more detailed description check this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/mergesort.html).

But the way, i'm sharing  my code. But, please first have an idea of how merge-sort works, otherwise you won't get anything from the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIM 1000005
int arr [LIM];              /* Array which stores the numerical values */
int temp[LIM];              /* Array which stores the temporary sorted numerical values */

void merge_it(int *arr,int low,int mid,int high) {
    int i = low;
    int j = mid+1;
    int k = low-1;

    while( i <= mid && j <= high ) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[j]) {
            temp[++k] = arr[i++];
        } else {
            temp[++k] = arr[j++];
        }
    }

    if(i > mid) {
        while(j <= high) {
            temp[++k] = arr[j++];
        }
    }

    else {
        while(i <= mid) {
            temp[++k] = arr[i++];
        }
    }

    for(i=low;  i<=k;   i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

void part_it(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;

    if(low<high) {
        mid = (low + high)/2;
        part_it (arr, low,   mid);
        part_it (arr, mid+1, high);
        merge_it(arr, low,   mid, high);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int n = -1;
    
    /* Take the input from the user */
    while(scanf("%i",&arr[++n])!=EOF);
    
    /* Start dividing the array     */
    part_it(arr,0,n-1);
    
    /* Print the sorted array       */
    for(i=0;    i<n;    i++) {
        printf("%i ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Pros:**
Its time-complexities are:

- Average - Case Time Complexity - **O(n.log(n))**
- Worst - Case Time Complexity   - **O(n.log(n))** *(Same,as the above)*

**Cons:**
It requires extra **O(n)** space to sort an array. It means, if you have **2 GB** numerical data and you want to sort it,then you require at least **4 GB** of free space in your RAM to sort it.

**EDIT:** There also exist an iterative way to carry out the merge sort, link mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation).

Comment: Other than as a learning exercise, a top down sort uses needless recursion to generate pairs of indices on the stack, requiring O(log(n)) space on the stack. A bottom up merge skips the needless recursion, and instead uses iteration to generate pairs of indices that first represent a run size of 1, then 2, then 4, then 8, ... until run size >= array size. Wiki link: [merge sort bottom up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) with a copy step that could be replaced by swapping pointers as noted in the comments in the example.

Comment: Quick sort takes at least O(log(n)) space on the stack.

Comment: @rcgldr Nice observation. :)